# Purescript FFI type definitions for constructor functions

Tags: javascript, types, titanium, ffi, purescript

I'm trying to wrap parts of the titanium api with PureScripts foreign function interface but I'm having trouble working out what the type definitions of the functions should be.

```
module Ti where

  foreign import data Window :: *

  foreign import window
    """ function (config) {
      return function () {
        return Ti.UI.createWindow(config);
      }
    } """ :: ??? -> Window

    foreign import open
    """ function (window) {
      return function () {
        window.open();
        return window;
      }
    } """ :: Window -> Window

    main = do
      w <- window ???
      open w
```

Comment: Not sure why you return a function of no arguments unless you expect to call `import` with `config` to create a function. Or is this supposed to be side-effecting?

Comment: @elclanrs I wanted to return a function with a single argument, I just wasn't sure what the type of that argument should be. I will be experimenting with Phil Freemans' answer using pursescript-options.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the `Foreign` type from the `purescript-foreign` library as the argument type, together with the [`purescript-options`](https://github.com/ethul/purescript-options) library to construct the appropriate options object.

I've written a short guide to the `purescript-options` library [here](https://gist.github.com/paf31/8e9177b20ee920480fbc#day-21---purescript-options), and there is another example in the project repository.